# Change background color of uisearchcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

How does one change the background colour of the uisearchcontroller? Atm it looks like this[image]

I want it all one colour. 
I've attempted `sc.view.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(10, green: 150, blue: 255)` and 
        `sc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(10, green: 150, blue: 255)` but doesn't remove the grey bit the side

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eh, with some thought I solved it.

`sc.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.rgb(10, green: 150, blue: 255)`

Answer (score 12):

```
     sc.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleProminent
     sc.searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage new]
     sc.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.rgb(10, green: 150, blue: 255)
```

set searchBarStyle to Prominent. It working for me

Answer (score 0):

This works for me simplely

```
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

according to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121871

Comment: according to the answer in the link this property has been added in iOS 13

Comment: targeted iOS 9 without any warning